# How to have an object as its passing a boundary appear as though its moving into a wall.?

Tags: objects

I want to have a simple sphere as it moves past a boundary it appears as though it is moving into a wall .
Then if the sphere moves back in opposite direction it appears to be coming out of a wall .
However there isn't actually a visible wall its just a boundary it moves past.

Comment: when you say "disappears" you mean becomes transparent?

Comment: “Moving into thin air and disappears” is one of those descriptions of an event in fantasy novels that can be interpreted about eighty-two different ways. Please be more precise.

Comment: As the sphere passes a boundary the sphere  looks as though its moving into a wall and becomes no longer visible . If the sphere then moves in opposite direction it appears as though its coming out of a wall.

Comment: you could use the solution I show or use a Boolean modifier for example

Answer (score 1):

You could give your sphere a material that is a mix between a *Principled BSDF* and a *Transparent* node, with a *Separate XYZ* as factor, and an empty that will control the gradient position. Choose the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* and select the empty as the *Object*:

[image]

[image]